# How to assign concret DbSet to Dbset<Interface>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, covariance

I don't know how to properly assign a concrete `DbSet` to a `DbSet<Interface>`

This is my GoogleToken class that implements IProviderToken:

```
public class GoogleToken : IProviderToken
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

And the same for DropboxToken:

```
public class DropboxToken : IProviderToken
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Then, how can assign the concret `DbSet<GoogleToken>` or `DbSet<DropboxToken>` to a `DbSet<IProviderToken>` in the following code?

```
public async Task<bool> AddExternalTokenAsync(IProviderToken providerToken)
{
    DbSet<IProviderToken> providerTokens = null;
    switch (providerToken.GetType().ToString())
    {
        case "Google":
            providerTokens = context.GoogleTokens;
            break;
        case "Dropbox":
            providerTokens = context.DropboxTokens;
            break;
    }

    ...
}
```

The error is in the line: `providerTokens = context.GoogleTokens;`
: Cannot implicitly convert type '`DbSet<GoogleToken>`' to '`DbSet<IProviderToken>`'

**Edited**

As far as I know the types are compatible, because I can do:

```
IProviderToken token = null;
switch (providerToken.GetType().ToString())
{
    case "Google":
        token = new GoogleToken();
        break;
    case "Dropbox":
        token = new DropboxToken();
        break;
}
```

So the problem seems on `DbSet`.

Comment: The types are not compatible, so no, you can't. You cannot look at a basket of oranges as if it is a basket of fruit, since that would cause problems if you  are trying to retrieve an apple from it. Because there are oranges in it.

Comment: @Maarten You wouldn't try to pick an 'apple' from a basket of fruit - that's against sense. The problem, to keep with your example is: If you would be able to treat a basket of oranges as a basket of fruit, you could then attempt to e.g. add any fruit to it - which would be a problem if this fruit was an apple.

Comment: @Maarten As far as I know the types are compatible: Please, see the Edited section in my question.

Comment: @Freerider Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx; my previous comment should give you a rough idea why `DbSet<T>` isn't covariant.

Comment: Or to move away from fruit analogies - if it worked as you intended, you could do this: `(context.DropboxTokens as DbSet<IProviderToken>).Add(new GoogleToken())`.

Comment: Getting a sense of generic covariance/contravariance would explain why they aren't compatible

Comment: @decPL Ok, I've understood it. Thank you.